# activerecord filter out based on foreign table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am tryng to create a association where Vacancy has one or many schedules & possibly many matchings

Now I need to get the vacancies that are 2 weeks before starting and that have no matching with state approved

```
Vacancy.includes(:schedules)
.where(schedules: {start_date: Date.today..Date.today+14})
.order("schedules.start_date ASC")
.includes(:matchings).where.not(matchings: {state: "approved"})
```

The first part works fine, I'm getting my vacancies and ordering them succesfully, although afterwards filtering out the ones that have a matching with approved does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```
Vacancy.includes(:schedules, :matchings)
.where(schedules: {start_date: Date.today..Date.today+14})
.order("schedules.start_date ASC")
.where.not(matchings: {state: "approved"})
```

its just the order of operations that you have a problem with

I took my own project to write this Relationship

```
Client.includes(:documents, :equipments).where(documents: {doc_type: 'equipment'} ).where(equipment: {shipper_id: 24}).count # 4

Client.includes(:documents, :equipments).where(documents: {doc_type: 'equipment'} ).where.not(equipment: {shipper_id: 24}).count # 314
```

Comment: This does not filter it out for some reason, the ones with state approved are still in the list.

Comment: Sanity check, when looping over the items and adding

if vacancy.matchings.where(state: "approved").count == 0

it works. Although, I don't want this dirty fix :)

Comment: I am looking into this now

Comment: @MartijnKerckhaert take a look at my examples for my own projects to see the counts

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try this?

```
Vacancy.joins(:schedules,:matchings).where(schedules: {start_date: Date.today..Date.today+14}).order("schedules.start_date ASC").where.not(matchings: {state: "approved"})
```

Comment: This does not filter it out for some reason, the ones with state approved are still in the list.